# Validation of a proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Let $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \space f \space$ is continuous and has the following property:
$\forall \space (a, b) \subset I, \space \exists \space c \in (a, b) \space$ so that $f(c) = 0$.

Show that $\forall \space x \in I, \space f(x) = 0$.

Proof:

Let $y \in I$

Since $f \space$ is continuous this means $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \space y}f(x) = f(y)$$

From the definition $\space(\delta, \varepsilon)\space$ of limits of functions this implies that $\forall \space \varepsilon > 0, \space \exists \space \delta(\varepsilon) = \delta > 0, \space$
so that if $\space |f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon \space$ then $|x - y| < \delta$

Assume $f(y) > 0$ and let $\varepsilon \le f(y) \Longleftrightarrow \space 0 \le f(y) - \varepsilon$

\begin{align*}
&|f(x) - f(y)| < \varepsilon \\
& 0 \le f(y) - \varepsilon < f(x) < \varepsilon + f(y) \\
& 0 < f(x) < \varepsilon + f(y)
\end{align*}

This concludes to $\forall \space \varepsilon \in (0, f(y)), \space f(x) \ne 0$.
Because $|x - y| < \delta$, then $y - \delta < x < y + \delta$ so this means that $x \in (y - \delta, y + \delta)$ and because $ f(x) \ne 0$, let $a = y - \delta$ and $b = y + \delta$ $\space \nexists \space c \in (a, b), \space f(c) = 0$, this is a contradiction.

The case when $f(y) < 0$ also leads to a contradiction, this can be similarly   proved by taking $\mathcal{E} \le -f(y)$.

This ends with the third case when $f(y) = 0$, since $y$ was arbitrarily chosen this means that $\forall \space x \in I, \space f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Well, what if the domain contains an isolated point $c\in I$? Then $f(c)$ could be anything, and nothing is violated (functions are continuous at isolated points). Seems like the domain should contain no isolated points for the statement to be true.

Comment: A proof by contradiction is much simpler.

Comment: $I$ can't have isolated points because if there is even one then you could choose an $a$ and a $b$ so that $(a, b) = ∅$ which means that $f$ doesn't satisfy it's property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the definition of limit backwards. The correct one is

> For all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that, if $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

This makes the proof invalid, I'm afraid.

Probably your assumption is that $I$ is an *open interval*.

The proof is then much easier. Suppose $f(y)>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $|x-y|<\delta$, $x\in I$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<f(y)/2$, which implies $f(x)>f(y)/2$.

Since you can choose a smaller $\delta_1>0$ such that $(y-\delta_1,y+\delta_1)\subset I$, this contradicts the assumption.

Similarly if $f(y)<0$.

Comment: If the interval is NOT opened, you can first prove the claim for the interiour of the interval, and extend it by continuity at the endpoints.